# How to write a script tag inside a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a javascript code which is called inside an iframe. I want to add a  tag inside that javascript code and append the  tag to the iframes parent body. This is my code to add the script tag and append to iframes parent body.

```
setTimeout(function () {
         var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)<";
         scriptTag +=  "/script>";
         $("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
    }, 5000);
```

the code isn't working it neither added the script tag nor showed any error

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: the code isn't working!!!!!!!!! it neither added the script tag nor showed any error

Comment: what is the exact requirement?

Comment: i have 2 js files, the first js file is called inside an iframe i want to call the 2nd file in the first js file and append it inside the parent body of the iframe

Comment: Import that other JS file using <script src=".."/> and then you can continue to use that(i.e. functionalitis provided by 2nd file). Why do you want to copy the content the of the 2nd file to 1st file?

Comment: i had tried that the js file got loaded but the js file is not getting append to iframe's parent body

Comment: If both the parent and the child page have the same origin (≅ domain name), you can do `window.parent.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', scriptTag);`

Comment: thanks for the help but got this text  "[object HTMLScriptElement]" instead of the tag

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys for all the ans I did figured out a way to add the tag and append it to the iframe's parent body.

```
setTimeout(function () {                     
              var imported = document.createElement('script');
              imported.src = 'src';
             parent.document.body.append(imported);
       }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may work better if you create a new script element and add that to the parent.

See this post for more information: [document.createElement('script') vs <script src="">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666658/document-createelementscript-vs-script-src)

This is an example copied from the accepted answer in the above link.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "...";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

The src property is the URL containing the script.

To add the script content to the element directly from a string you need the answer from:
[Adding <script> element to the DOM and have the javascript run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run)

So your question example code would be:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
var code = 'alert(1);';
try {
  scriptTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  $("#iframe").contents().find("body").appendChild(scriptTag);
} catch (e) {
  scriptTag.text = code;
  $("#iframe").contents().find("body").appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

Also see this post for more details on how to attach the script element: [document.head, document.body to attach scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557868/document-head-document-body-to-attach-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Your `scriptTag` is a string and not an HTML element, so you are just appending the string. You have to use `document.createElement`

```
setTimeout(function () {
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
     scriptTag.src = 'alert(1)'
     $("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method using vanilla javascript.
this work for me I guaranteed this work for you to

```
function insertScript(script) {
  var head = document.head;

  var createScript = document.createElement('script');
  createScript.innerHTML = script;
  createScript.setAttribute('defer', '');

  head.appendChild(createScript);
}

let myScript = `
  var a = 1 + 2;
  alert(a);
`; // You can write anything you want

insertScript(myScript);
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help

```
setTimeout(function () {
     var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)</" + "script>";
     $("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/25/gotchas-with-dynamically-adding-script-tags-to-html