# head.appendChild giving error in console but working fine

Tags: javascript, inject, script-tag

I am trying to inject a script on page load in head wherein I have to give the page name inside script. 
Below is how I am implementing it in my ts file.

```
**var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var tag = document.createElement("script");
 tag.type = 'text/javascript';
 tag.innerHTML = "var DDO = {} DDO.pageData = {'pageName': " + pageUrl + "} ";
 head.appendChild(tag);**
```

The script is getting injected however an error is being thrown in the console tab.

> ERROR: VM3741:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at appendChild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],pageUrl="somevalue";
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.type = 'text/javascript';
tag.textContent = "var DDO = {}; DDO.pageData = {'pageName': '" + pageUrl + "'} ";
head.appendChild(tag);
```

**To remove previous script element**

```
var script = head.childNodes[0]; //get previous script element
head.removeChild(script); //removing script
```

you have not provided single quotes for the value of the key pageName

Comment: Thanks a lot **Aman** . Saved my night.  Just another question. If I want to remove this tag before injecting another one, how can I do that. 
Like I said in my problem statement, I want to inject this tag on page change, and make sure that the previous tag is removed. 
Your reply will be much https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682062/aman-kumayuappreciated.

Comment: I want to remove the tag by id. 
tag.id = "test";
Now I want to remove this particular tag with this id. 
Is it possible?

Comment: I basically wants to do something like this.

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.id = "test";
    tag.textContent = "var DDO = {}; DDO.pageData = {'pageName': '" + pageUrl + "'} ";
    if (this._dataLayerInjected) {
      var script = head.childNodes[0]; //get previous script element
      head.removeChild(script); //removing script
    } else {
      head.appendChild(tag)
      this._dataLayerInjected = true;
    }

Remove this particular tag with id : test

Comment: you cannot add an id to a script element, it can only have src, charset, defer, type, async

Comment: Actually, head.childNodes[0] is not working. 
When I debugged it came at head.childNodes[head.childNodes.length +1]. So basically I just want to replace this particular tag on every page load. 
And apart from that there are other scripts as well which should not get affected. 

Will be really thankful if you have a solution.

Comment: replace this head.childNodes[head.childNodes.length +1] with this head.childNodes[head.childNodes.length -1]

Comment: Yes I did that. However is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: what you actually want to do ?

Comment: I have a angular JS application, wherein on page load, I want to inject a script with above information, and then on page change, only previous script tag should be removed and a new script tag should be injected with the fresh value of pageurl.

Comment: I think you can only achieve this with basic JS

Answer (score 1):

tag.innerHTML = "var DDO = {}***;*** DDO.pageData = {'pageName': " + pageUrl + "} ";
semicolon missing after defining the variable DDO, 
and also from where are you injecting in pageUrl, make sure variable is defined.

try having script in external file and injecting in script tag with refrence to that file in case some error in script defined in inner html

[document.head, document.body to attach scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557868/document-head-document-body-to-attach-scripts)

Comment: External file script is not required here, can be done within script tag

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.id = 'adobedatalayer';
    tag.textContent = 'var DDO = {}; DDO.pageData =' + JSON.stringify(pageinfo);
    var script = document.getElementById('adobedatalayer');
    if (script != null) {
      head.removeChild(script);
    }
    head.appendChild(tag);
```